# Shadow displaying as square on FloatingActionButton Glide V4

Tags: android, android-view, floating-action-button, android-glide

I recently upgraded Glide to version 4 which has caused problems with the image I display in a floating action button. I have attempted 2 methods and I use the same XML for both:

XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/profilepic_fab"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/bookmark_checked_white" />
```

Method #1:

```
            RequestOptions optionsCentre = new RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.profilepic_placeholder)
                    error(R.drawable.profilepic_placeholder).dontTransform()
                    .dontAnimate().CircleCrop();

            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(userinfo.getprofilePic())
                    .apply(optionsCentre)
                    .into(profilepic);
```

Result of Method #1: It looks good on Android 7.1.2 but on 4.4 it looks like the image below:

[image]

Method #2:

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                .fitCenter()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.profilepic_placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.profilepic_placeholder)
                .priority(Priority.HIGH);

    Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .apply(options)
            .load(url)
            .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(fab) {
                @Override
                protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                    RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                            RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
                    circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                    fab.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                }
            });
```

Result of Method #2: The results look different on Android 7.1.2 and 4.4

Android 7.1.2:

[image]

Android 4.4:

[image]

Method #2 is what used to work with Glide v3... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `FloatingActionButton`, its not possible to achieve your expected behavior for all Android versions.

Instead of `FloatingActionButton`, use `ImageView` with 3rd party library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load and transform your `Image` resource. You can also use [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) library.

> **SOLUTION 1:**

Using `ImageView` with `Picasso`.

**Gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    .........
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

**Usage:**

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dummy_background"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA

```
ImageView imageProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_profile_pic);
Picasso.with(this)
        .load(R.drawable.dummy_profile_pic)
        .resize(150, 150)
        .centerCrop()
        .transform(new CircleTransform())
        .into(imageProfilePic);
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

> **SOLUTION 2:**

Using `ImageView` with `Glide`.

**Gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    .........
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
}
```

**Usage:**

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dummy_background"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA

```
ImageView imageProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_profile_pic);


Glide.with(this)
        .load(R.drawable.dummy_profile_pic)
        .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
        .into(imageProfilePic);
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

> **SOLUTION 3:**

Using `CircleImageView` library.

**Gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    .........
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
}
```

**Usage:**

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dummy_background"/>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/image_profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"        
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFF"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA

```
CircleImageView imageProfilePic = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_profile_pic);

Picasso.with(this)
        .load(R.drawable.dummy_profile_pic)
        .into(imageProfilePic);
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution! I've had to implement it with an ImageView but I'm struggling to get a shadow that has a gradient. I've only been able to make solid grey boarder around the ImageView not a shadow the decreases in opacity going outwards. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

[`FloatingActionButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) cannot take arbitrary width/height values, instead use [`app:fabSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#attr_android.support.design:fabSize) attribute to provide an input size from 3 of available sizes: auto, mini, and normal.

Specify `layout_width` and `layout_height` of FAB as `wrap_content`, and provide the desired fab size using `app:fabSize="normal"` (or other parameter from the list).

<sup>This question look similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44759018/1083957).</sup>

Comment: The thing is that it used to be able to take in arbitrary width/height values when I was using Glide 3.7/3.8. I think I'll just have to use an image view and a custom shadow.

Comment: Why are you using a FAB? Use an ImageView.

Comment: I'm using it because I what a circular ImageView that has a graded shadow